# How can i add title attributes in links using the Yii2 framework?

Tags: php, yii2

I created a navigation menu in yii2 and i have links generated by the following code:

```
  <?= HeaderNavigation::widget([
                'options' => ['class' => 'nav nav-tabs border-0 flex-column flex-lg-row'],
                'itemOptions' => [
                    'class' => 'nav-item',
                ],
                'items' => [
                    [
                        'label' => Yii::t('lang', 'Browse'),
                        'url' => ['directory/index'],
                        'icon' => 'home',
                        'title' => 'HELLO WORLD'
                    ],
                    
                ],
            ]) ?>
```

but title attribute doesn't work. What i m doing wrong??

Comment: What widget are you using for menu? In `yii\widgets\Menu` you just need to put the `title` into the `options` sub-array like this `'options' => ['title' => 'HELLO WORLD'],` but that widget doesn't have `icon` option for items, so you are probably using something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally i managed to make it work with the help of Michal Hynčica.

I had to use `options` key:

```
'options' => ['title' => 'HELLO WORLD'],
```

so the code should be:

```
'items' => [
                    [
                        'options' => ['title' => 'HELLO WORLD'],
                        'label' => Yii::t('lang', 'Browse'),
                        'url' => ['directory/index'],
                        'icon' => 'home',
                        'title' => 'HELLO WORLD'
                    ],
```